# Incorrect number of arguments expected 8, got 0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE novi_korisnik (korisnik_id INT, new_ime varchar(45), new_prezime varchar(60), new_datum_rodj DATE, new_drzava_rodj varchar(45), new_email varchar(45), new_korisnicko_ime varchar(45), new_biografija TEXT)
BEGIN
insert into korisnik ( ime, prezime, datum_rodj, drzava_rodj, email, korisnicko_ime, biografija) values ( new_ime, new_prezime, new_datum_rodj, new_drzava_rodj, new_email, new_korisnicko_ime, new_biografija);
END
```

Please help me with these procedure
Result is INCORRECT NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS

Comment: Your SP declares 8 parameters but is receiving no arguments. How do you invoke the SP?

Comment: CALL novi_korisnik;

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It sounds like MySQL. You just pass no arguments. Just pass arguments to your SP like `CALL novi_korisnik(1, 'any ime', 'any prezime', NOW(), 'any drzava_rodj', 'any email', 'any korisnicko_ime', 'some biografija text here')`. Or refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Yes, there doesnt look as though there are issues with your procedure, Just looks as though you are not passing any values into your SP when you call it.